# Why does my plot have these sit labels all over it? I am plotting an RDA

Tags: r, plot, rda

[image]

```
library(vegan)
buoy.rda <- rda(buoy_means, weather)
ef <- envfit(buoy.rda, weather, permutations = 1000)
ef
plot(buoy.rda)
plot(ef)
```

The `buoy_means` file columns are labeled by buoy ID (which is the red blob) not sit#

Comment: hey! can you please add a reproducible example so we can help you better

Answer (score 0):

The red labels are the column names of your first matrix (X, or `buoy_means` in your case), the blue labels (and arrows) correspond to the column names of the second matrix (Y, or `weather` in your case), and the black labels are the row names of both X and Y (since they should match).

By default, sites, species and "biplot arrows" are displayed byt the `plot` function. To know more about that, see [the help file of `plot.cca`](https://rdrr.io/cran/vegan/man/plot.cca.html) (`?plot.cca`). The argument to change to have a different behaviour is `display`:

> `display` Scores shown. These must include some of the alternatives
> "species" or "sp" for species scores, sites or "wa" for site scores,
> "lc" for linear constraints or LC scores, or "bp" for biplot arrows or
> "cn" for centroids of factor constraints instead of an arrow, and
> "reg" for regression coefficients (a.k.a. canonical coefficients). The
> alternative "all" selects all available scores.

Example with sites on plot

```
data(dune)
data(dune.env)
dune.Manure <- rda(dune ~ Manure, dune.env)
plot(dune.Manure)
```

[image: RDA plot with sites]

and without sites

```
plot(dune.Manure, display = c("sp", "bp"))
```

[image: RDA plot without sites]

Comment: How do I get it to not show the row labels?

Comment: I'm editing my answer right now to show how to not display the "site labels"